# htaccess rewriting and redirecting with get parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, get, wamp

I have tried everything i could find in here. Maybe its my wamp config or maybe that the website is not in root, i have no idea. Basically some stuff worked some didnt.

What i want to achieve is remove index.php and all .php extensions altogether and force add a trailing slash / at the end.

Also i would like to pass a GET parameter after a second "/".

For Example

localhost/index.php -> localhost/
localhost/search.php -> localhost/search/
localhost/search.php?d=1 -> localhost/search/1/

My httpd-vhosts.conf :

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/?payday/$ /index.php [END]
    RewriteRule ^/?payday/(\w)/?$ /$1.php [END]
    RewriteRule ^/?payday/(\w)/([^/])/?$ /$1.php?param=$2 [END]
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?payday/$ /index.php [END]
RewriteRule ^/?payday/(\w)/?$ /$1.php [END]
RewriteRule ^/?payday/(\w)/([^/])/?$ /$1.php?param=$2 [END]
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to implement such a combination of things usually is to do it one by one:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ /index.php [END]
RewriteRule ^/?(\w+)/?$ /$1.php [END]
RewriteRule ^/?(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ /$1.php?param=$2 [END]
```

You might be able to be more precise about that http GET parameter. If it always is a numerical ID as typical then use the more precise pattern `^/?(\w)/([0-9])/?$` which will speed things up a bit.

If, as you suggest, though your question is contradictory here, if your application logic is not placed in the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder but in a subfolder, then implement specific rules and leave the dynamic configuration file (".htaccess") at top level. That prevents unexpected behavior:

```
RewriteRule ^/?subfolder/?$ /index.php [END]
RewriteRule ^/?subfolder/(\w+)/?$ /$1.php [END]
RewriteRule ^/?subfolder/(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ /$1.php?d=$2 [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. First thing i did was reinstalled my wamp server now apache is 2.4.41. Then i checked if .htaccess file works at all which looks like it does, if i break it i get an error. I downloaded different browser in case it was cached. I have tried it with [L] and [END] flags. Still it only removes .php extension, doesnt force the slash and doesnt pass the GET parameter.

Comment: Why would you want to force a trailing slash? What for? The rules I posted accept _both_ versions likewise, with or without trailing slash. Since that does not really carry information it makes little sense to insist in that...

Comment: Oh sorry, I named the parameter "param", only now I see that you called it "d" in your question. I changed the rule accordingly.

Comment: Nah the name isnt the issue, i dont get any get parameters at all

Comment: You edited your question and posted a static and a dynamic configuration file. Both implementing the same rewriting rules. That does not make sense. If you have access to the server configuration (as you apparently have) then there is no sense in using a dynamic configuration file (".htacces"). I explained that in the answer.

Comment: The rules in the answer will define a http get parameter. Please post the exact URL that gets requested where you say no such parameter is set.

Comment: the point being is that it doesnt work either way. http://localhost/payday/search/1345 doesnt return any get parameters

Comment: There was a bug in the rules, I fixed it and added some "+" characters. But this is strange: with the rules you copied none of the rules except the index one could have ever get applied. So I wonder at what results you are looking. Did you really make sure that your cache is cleared or that you use a fresh anonymous browser tab?

Comment: Yeah its weird, i can get it to work only like this
RewriteRule ^/?(\w+)-(\w+)/?$ $1.php?param=$2 [END]
localhost/payday/search-1345

Comment: That means that you have some other rule in place somewhere that intervenes beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the answer you will hear, but a solution for nice URLs. Feel free to adapt and expand the code.

For my websites (here ct.wiimm.de) I use:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite base path (not really needed, but helpful on conflicts)
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]

# for pages with sub-path support
# -> eg.g This allows /stat/a/b/c to be send to /stat.php
RewriteRule ^((stat|tdis)/[^/.]*)/(.*) /$1.php/$3 [L]

# add .php, if not found but .php exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .* $0.php [L]

# redirect to main index.php, if nout found
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

And then PHP delivers all links without `.php` suffix.